# My SecondActivity crashes when have more than Three ImageButton is placed

Tags: java, android, android-layout

When i am placing three images in my activity it crashes.Can't able to find out 
 the issue.

**First activity**

```
public class SquareMain extends AppCompatActivity {//MainActivity

    private boolean isUserClickedBackButton = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {//OnCreate
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_square_main);
        mainmusic();
    }//OnCreate

    public void presshere(View view)//pressherebutton
    {
            Intent press = new Intent(SquareMain.this, SquareHome.class);
            startActivity(press);
    }//pressherebutton

    public void mainmusic(){//mainmusic
        MediaPlayer mainmusic = MediaPlayer.create(SquareMain.this, R.raw.mainmeunsong);//main music
        mainmusic.start();//main music
        mainmusic.setLooping(true);//main music
    }

}//MainActivity
```

**Second activity**

```
public class SquareHome extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_square_home);
    }
}
```

**Image button**

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/pressherebutton"
    android:layout_width="161dp"
    android:layout_height="28dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@mipmap/squarepresshere"
    android:onClick="presshere"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:text="@string/presshere"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.86"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/squarepresshere"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="223dp" />
```

my SecondActivity crashes when more than three image button is placed.
Anyone that might have any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: where is the image button in the code? Please include the crash log in the question

Comment: i edit the question and place in the image button code

Comment: Could you include the logcat? Can't figure out the issue without it.

Comment: i got it but thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to terminate your `MediaPlayer` before leaving the `Activity`, override `onPause` method  and stop your `MediaPlayer`. declare your `mainmusic` as class variable not local.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mainmusic != null) {
        if (mainmusic.isPlaying())
            mainmusic.stop();
        mainmusic.reset();
        mainmusic.release();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the size of those images?? Size of an images is also the factors we have to consider for smooth and comfortable to render images. High resolution images may cause ANR.